# Capture righclick event on Flash plugin using JS when using WMODE="window"

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, browser, flash

I'm using a custom right click context menu for a flash app (overriding the default adobe menu). For this Uza's right click solution ( http://www.uza.lt/blog/2007/08/solved-right-click-in-as3 ) works well.

However, flash player plugin (for Firefox/Chrome etc) has a bug which breaks usage of international characters when its using WMode for the html embed. WMode="widnow" works.

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-501

The issue can be seen better here -

http://www.5etdemi.com/blog/archives/2005/06/firefox-wmodetransparent-is-completely-screwy-and-breaks-textfields/

**The problem**

I need to capture the right click event fired from Flash player plugin to the web browser container without using WMode on the html embed tag (ie. WMode="window")

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907668/capture-right-click-through-javascript-withouth-wmode

Comment: Just a note: be careful with opaque or transparent wmode, see what Tinic Uro says:
old one (but still true for backward compatibility):
http://www.kaourantin.net/2005/01/wmode-and-flash-video.html
new one:
http://www.kaourantin.net/2010/02/core-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

The right-click JS hack works in opaque and transparent mode because the browser is rendering the Flash inside its own display tree. In this mode, the browser receives mouse events, allows them to be handled by JS, then passes them to the Flash plugin. (This is the reason why there are bugs with entering accented or non-latin characters in transparent mode, because some browsers don't pass them through properly).

In the other window modes the Flash object is not part of the html DOM in the same way. Instead it is just given a rectangle of the display and can draw to it directly. It also gets its keyboard and mouse events from the OS directly, so I wouldn't expect any JS context menu hacks to work in any mainstream browser.